# How do I return a String Enum's value from a RESTful service using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, enums

I have an enum that contains only three values, including one with spaces:

```
public enum ResultEnum {
    Sold("Sold"),
    No_deal_today("No deal today"),
    Appointment("Appointment");
    
    private String result;
    
    private ResultEnum(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    
    public static ResultEnum fromResult(String result) {
        switch (result) {
        case "Sold":
            return ResultEnum.Sold;
 
        case "No deal today":
            return ResultEnum.No_deal_today;
 
        case "Appointment":
            return ResultEnum.Appointment;
 
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResultEnum [" + result
                    + "] not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

I created a converter for it:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ResultConverter implements AttributeConverter<ResultEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ResultEnum resultEnum) {
        return resultEnum.getResult();
    }

    @Override
    public ResultEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String result) {
        return ResultEnum.fromResult(result);
    }

}
```

This works great, except that it returns the Enum value in the results:

```
"result": "No_deal_today"
```

**Is there a way to return the string value from the controller rather than the ENUM value?**

```
"result": "No deal today"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was add the @JsonValue annotation to getResult():

```
@JsonValue
public String getResult() {
    return result;
}
```